# performance of scala vs java for the problem "Min Steps in Infinite Grid" (close)

Tags: java, scala

I have 2 functions do the same logic in Scala and Java.

I wrote solution in Scala:

```
def coverPoints(A: Array[Int], B: Array[Int]): Int = {
    def diff(x1: Int, x2: Int, y1: Int, y2: Int): Int = Math.max(Math.abs(x1 - x2), Math.abs(y1 - y2))

    @tailrec
    def coverPoints(total: Int, arr1: List[Int], arr2: List[Int]): Int =
      if (arr1.length <= 1) total else coverPoints(total + diff(arr1(0), arr1(1), arr2(0), arr2(1)), arr1.tail, arr2.tail)

    coverPoints(0, A.toList, B.toList)
  }
```

But this solution hits `Time Limit Exceeded`. Then I wrote it with Java:

```
private int diff(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    return Math.max(Math.abs(x1 - x2), Math.abs(y1 - y2));
}

public int coverPoints(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a == null || a.length <= 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    int distant = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        distant += diff(a[i], b[i], a[i + 1], b[i + 1]);
    }
    return distant;
}
```

But the system talks with me that performance of Scala code is not good enough. And Java passes the performance check. How can optimize the performance of this Scala function?

Comment: Probably because the Scala version uses recursion and far more object creation, while the Java version uses a loop and no object creation while iterating over the loop.

Comment: But as I know, scala compiler will change @tailrec to for loop and list.tail is not create new object

Comment: I don't have time to do benchmarks now, but I suspect that maybe accessing list elements by an index is slow. Can you change your `coverPoints` to version using pattern matching? `@tailrec
    def coverPoints(total: Int, arr1: List[Int], arr2: List[Int]): Int =
      (arr1, arr2) match {
        case (List(_), _) => total
        case (x1 :: x2 :: xs, y1 :: y2 :: ys) => coverPoints(total + diff(x1, x2, y1, y2), xs, ys)
      }`. Maybe it would help ;)

Comment: TLE is specific to coding sites. Which one are you using? Most have a discussion panel for each question - have you checked there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you are changing the `Array` parameters to `List` parameters. Indexing a list, `arr1(1)`, and getting the length of a list, `arr1.length`, are both linear operations. Both of those ops are much faster on an array.

Also, you don't really need to recurse at all.

```
def coverPoints(a: Array[Int], b: Array[Int]): Int =
  a.indices.init.fold(0){ case (acc,idx) =>
    acc + Math.max(Math.abs(a(idx) - a(idx+1)), Math.abs(b(idx) - b(idx+1)))
  }
```